# how to Get the value of TD in a foreach loop using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i am using a foreach loop in table and **i want a button on each row and on click i want to get that value** so i tried this code

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<tr>
   <td>
 <button onclick='linkproduct();' data-rowid="{{ $product->id }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Use Current Location</button>
     </td>
       </tr>
@endforeach
```

javascript

```
<script>
    function linkproduct(){
    var userId = $(this).data('rowid');
    console.log(userId);
}
</script>
```

but error is undefined in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling your function with a specific `this` binding.

You can instead pass an argument: `onclick="linkproduct(this)"` and then process the argument in your function (not `this`):

```
function linkproduct(button){
    var userId = $(button).data('rowid');
    console.log(userId);
}
```

Or, if you prefer to stick with `this`, then provide the correct `this` with `onclick="linkproduct.call(this)"`